is there a way to access the list of points of a specific star's light curve in the ogle variable star database?
I am looking to do a machine learning project where I classify the type of variable star for the light curve. In doing this, I need to find a list of points of the graph of the variable star on ogle. Is there a way of obtaining this on the ogle collection of variable stars? Or do I need to use another tool, and if so, what would this tool be?
